# Alertdialog error in Xamarin (Mono) Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I searched internet and couldnt find a solution. This is the best i could develop myself. But I get error on first line. I get this error:

```
Error CS0428: Cannot convert method group 'Create' to non-delegate type 'Android.App.AlertDialog'. Did you intend to invoke the method? (CS0428)
```

My code is:

```
AlertDialog alertMessage = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).Create;

alertMessage.SetTitle("MobileSecure Key:");

alertMessage.SetMessage(cipherText);

alertMessage.Show();
```

Answer (score 3):

One simple answer is to try calling the method by adding some brackets `Create()`

Beyond that, there's an excellent introduction to dialogs including many samples which show how to call them at http://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2013/02/using-dialogs-in-mono-for-android.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.SetTitle("msgConfirm");
        alert.SetMessage("msgSureExit");            
        Dialog dialog = alert.Create();
        dialog.Show();
```

I hope this will help someone :)